# Why i get Error converting data type varchar to float error in bcp query out?

Tags: sql-server

I'm new in `sql server`,write this bcp query for save select query result to csv file:

```
declare @Price as float
set @Price=1744

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select [Telno],[Cycle],[Price] FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[CycleAnalysisTable] where CONVERT(float, [Price])>''CONVERT(float, @Price)''" queryout d:\F.txt -c -T'
```

But when i run that query,get this error:

> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error
>   converting data type varchar to float.

How can i solve that problem?thanks all.

Comment: @alex thanks to pay attention to my problem,because,on the table price save with varchar(max) data type.

Comment: @alex,no that not solve my problem,

Comment: @alex my friend that's not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got quotes, that is why your query ran as:

```
select [Telno],[Cycle],[Price] 
FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[CycleAnalysisTable] 
where CONVERT(float, [Price])>'CONVERT(float, @Price)'
```

And SQL Server can not CONVERT `CONVERT(float, @Price)` to float.

Try to run it like this:

```
declare @Price as float,
        @Query nvarchar(max),
        @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT  @Price=1744

SELECT @Query = 'select [Telno],[Cycle],[Price] FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[CycleAnalysisTable] where CONVERT(float, [Price])>' +CAST(@Price as varchar(100))


SELECT @sql= 'EXEC xp_cmdshell ''bcp "'+@Query+'" queryout d:\F.txt -c -T'''

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

**EDIT**

One more way:

```
declare @Price as float,
        @bcp varchar(max)

SELECT @Price=1744

SELECT @bcp= 'bcp "select [Telno],[Cycle],[Price] FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[CycleAnalysisTable] where CONVERT(float, [Price])>' +CAST(@Price as nvarchar(100))+'" queryout d:\F.txt -c -T'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcp
```

Comment: thanks to pay attention to my problem,please wait to test that.

Comment: The first query is too complicated (EXEC inside EXEC) better use second solution, it is much more simple.

Comment: My pleasure! :)